# Object following Player

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am messing around in Unity and wanted to make a mechanic where a box would touch another object and then that object would follow the Player.

I have Cube set up like this:[image: Cube Inspector]

And a Sphere with a Box Collider with same options.

My Player script is thus:

```
public class Player : MonoBehaviour {

public float speed = 0.0f;
public float moveX = 0.0f;
public float moveY = 0.0f;
public GameObject player;
public GameObject obj;
//public float force = 0.0f;
private bool collided = false;


// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    player = GameObject.FindWithTag ("Player");
}

// Update is called once per frame
void FixedUpdate () {
    moveX = Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal");
    moveY = Input.GetAxis ("Vertical");
    player.GetComponent<Rigidbody> ().velocity = new Vector2 (moveX * speed, moveY * speed);    
}

void OnCollisionEnter (Collision col) {
    if (col.gameObject == obj) {
        collided = true;
    }
}

void OnCollisionExit (Collision col) {
    if (col.gameObject == obj) {
        collided = false;
    }
}

void Update () {
    if(collided) {
        obj.transform.position = (player.transform.position - obj.transform.position)*speed;
    }
}

}
```

What have I yet to do? Hoping someone can nudge me in the right direction.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will provide you two scripts.

1st Script is FollowTarget. This will follow your target forcely.

2nd Script is SmoothFollow which will follow your target in a smooth movement.

## FollowTarget.cs

```
using System;
using UnityEngine;

public class FollowTarget : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform target;
    public Vector3 offset = new Vector3(0f, 7.5f, 0f);


    private void LateUpdate()
    {
        transform.position = target.position + offset;
    }
}
```

## SmoothFollow.cs

```
using UnityEngine;


public class SmoothFollow : MonoBehaviour
{

    // The target we are following
    [SerializeField]
    private Transform target;
    // The distance in the x-z plane to the target
    [SerializeField]
    private float distance = 10.0f;
    // the height we want the camera to be above the target
    [SerializeField]
    private float height = 5.0f;

    [SerializeField]
    private float rotationDamping;
    [SerializeField]
    private float heightDamping;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start() { }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void LateUpdate()
    {
        // Early out if we don't have a target
        if (!target)
            return;

        // Calculate the current rotation angles
        var wantedRotationAngle = target.eulerAngles.y;
        var wantedHeight = target.position.y + height;

        var currentRotationAngle = transform.eulerAngles.y;
        var currentHeight = transform.position.y;

        // Damp the rotation around the y-axis
        currentRotationAngle = Mathf.LerpAngle(currentRotationAngle, wantedRotationAngle, rotationDamping * Time.deltaTime);

        // Damp the height
        currentHeight = Mathf.Lerp(currentHeight, wantedHeight, heightDamping * Time.deltaTime);

        // Convert the angle into a rotation
        var currentRotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, currentRotationAngle, 0);

        // Set the position of the camera on the x-z plane to:
        // distance meters behind the target
        transform.position = target.position;
        transform.position -= currentRotation * Vector3.forward * distance;

        // Set the height of the camera
        transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x ,currentHeight , transform.position.z);

        // Always look at the target
        transform.LookAt(target);
    }
}
```

Just choose one of them and then attach it to the gameObject. Like another box that is suppose to follow.

Remove your Update() function in your script as you don't need it anymore.

Also Remove your OnCollisionExit()

```
void OnCollisionEnter (Collision col) {
    if (col.gameObject == obj) {

        // If you choose to use SmoothFollow Uncomment this.
        //col.GetComponent<SmoothFollow>().target = this.transform;

        // If you choose to use FollowTarget Uncomment this
        //col.GetComponent<FollowTarget>().target = this.transform;
    }
}
```